# What is the hardest winnable tic-tac-toe-ish game?

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, tic-tac-toe

A tic-tac-toe-ish game is a game on an infinite where the goal is to claim a specific set of cells reflected, rotated, or translated where each player takes turns claiming a cell. A winnable tic-tac-toe-ish game is such a game which the first player can win. How big can the winning set of cells be for the game to still be winnable?

Comment: Where does this problem come from? What have you done so far trying to solve it? Is there any existing literature on tic-tac-toe-ish games?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The case where target set is a polyomino was originally proposed by Harary, referred to as generalized tic-tac-toe or animal tic-tac-toe. Determining the largest polyomino which the first player can achieve is an open problem.

The situation for tetrominos is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4355825/177399). The square tetromino is a loser, but all others are winners. We also know the entire story for pentominos; the Y, L, and N pentominos are winners, while all others are losers. Moving up to hexominos, we know that most of the shapes are losers, simply because they contain a smaller previously proven loser as a subset. However, for the hexomino shown below, lovingly dubbed "Snaky" by Martin Garder, it is an open problem to determine if it is a winner or a loser! This is only open case; every polyomino of size 7 or more contains a previously proven loser, so is a loser.

Therefore, it is unknown whether the largest winnable polyonimo has size five or six.

[image]

I do not know what happens for more general target sets, i.e. ones that are only diagonally connected, or not connected at all.

---

Below is a pictorial proof that all of the displayed shapes are actually losers. The second player forces a draw by using the pairing strategy described in the figure. This image was taken from

> H. Harborth, M. Seemann, Snaky is a paving winner, Bull. Inst. Combin. Appl. 19 (1997), 71–78

**Edit:** As pointed out by Spitemaster in a comment, the picture in the original paper contained a mistake. I fixed this mistake, so the picture below is correct.

[image]

Comment: For purposes of this question, it seems like any only-diagonally-connected animal is equivalent to an orthogonally-connected one under a transformation something like a 45-degree rotation.  Interesting cases will be animals with both diagonal and orthogonal connections..

Comment: What about disconnected set of target cells? For example: `XX...XX` where `.` are empty(not needed) are `X` cells that must be filled?

Comment: The proof that the hexomino in the third column is a loser is wrong.  Rotate it 90 degrees and the provided paving doesn't prevent its completion.

Comment: @Spitemaster Thank you for pointing that out. It turns out that hexomino belongs in the leftmost column. I am dismayed that got past peer review!